# mysql delete successive rows

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I have the following query:

```
select count(*)
FROM
    cumul AS t1,
    cumul AS t2
WHERE
    t1.id+1 = t2.id
and
    t2.spec_datetime-t1.spec_datetime < 0.001
and
    t1.id < 100000
and
    t1.v1-t2.v1 = 0
and
    t1.v2-t2.v2 =0;
```

I want to delete the same records with:

```
DELETE FROM cumul AS t1, cumul AS t2
WHERE
    t1.id+1 = t2.id
and
    t2.spec_datetime-t1.spec_datetime < 0.001
and
    t1.v1-t2.v1 = 0
and
    t1.v2-t2.v2 = 0;
```

I get:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS t1
>   , cumul AS t2 WHERE t1.id+1 = t2.id and t2.spec_datetime-t1.spec_datetime <' at
>   line 1

How can I correct the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE t1 FROM cumul AS t1, cumul AS t2  
       ^^
Just add alias before FROM
```

So try this:

```
DELETE t1 FROM cumul AS t1, cumul AS t2
WHERE
    t1.id+1 = t2.id
and
    t2.spec_datetime-t1.spec_datetime < 0.001
and
    t1.v1-t2.v1 = 0
and
    t1.v2-t2.v2 = 0;
```

Refer [MySQL :: 13.2.2. DELETE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You must specify which table in the table list to delete from (even though they're the same table in this instance):

```
DELETE t1 FROM cumul AS t1, cumul AS t2...
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html